# User account is disabled - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a web application that uses Spring Security 4.0.2 to authenticate users' username/password.

When I try to login using an existing username, spring security tells me that "User account is disabled", but I don't know how to change this.

My context:

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/private/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- Erro aqui -->
    <form-login login-page="/public/login.xhtml"
        username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/public/login.xhtml?login_error=1"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/public/login.xhtml" />
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<b:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="br.com.jway.security.UrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT login,senha,role FROM usuario WHERE login = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT login, role FROM usuario WHERE login = ? " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Anybody knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

```
    I was also facing the same issue. Just return "true" in isEnabled method where you are implementing " UserDetails "
    
    public class UserPrinciple implements UserDetails {
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard `JDBC` implementation of the `UserDetailsService` (`JdbcDaoImpl`) requires tables to load the password, account status (enabled or disabled) and a list of authorities (roles) for the user.

The problem is your query does **not** load the account status:

```
users-by-username-query="SELECT login,senha,role FROM usuario WHERE login = ?
```

This query should give `username`, `password` and `enabled`. I guess you should replace the `role` with `enabled` and i have no idea what the `senha` is actually!

Answer (score 0):

Extend your query to fetch the `enabled` attribute as well:

**users-by-username-query**: An SQL statement to query a username, password, and enabled status given a username. The default is

```
select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?
```

You find detailed information in the [Spring Security Documentation, JDBC User Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-jdbc-user-service).